# Why does e.stopPropagation() not work?

Tags: javascript, event-bubbling, stoppropagation

I am reading a book called "Adaptive Web Design" by Aaron Gustafson were I got a piece of javascript that I didnt understand. While researching I find out about the difference between returning false and e.preventDefault. I also now know a little bit about the bubbeling effect of JavaScript and came to understand that to stop the bubbeling you can use e.stopPropagation() (in none-ie browser atleast).

I was playing around in fiddle but I couldnt get it working. I think it might got to do with the way the bubbeling takes effect (from root to the element and back?).

```
document.body.onclick = function (e) {
    alert("Fired a onclick event!");
    e.preventDefault();
    if ('bubbles' in e) { // all browsers except IE before version 9
        if (e.bubbles) {
            e.stopPropagation();
            alert("The propagation of the event is stopped.");
        } else {
            alert("The event cannot propagate up the DOM hierarchy.");
        }
    } else { // Internet Explorer before version 9
        // always cancel bubbling
        e.cancelBubble = true;
        alert("The propagation of the event is stopped.");
    }
}
```

Here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/MekZii/pmekd/ (FIXED link)
EDIT:
I copy-pasted the wrong link! Its fixed now!

So what I would like to see is that when you click on the anchor, the onclick that is used on the div doesn't get executed (this is not a practical case, just a study case!)

Comment: That code you link to does not resemble the code in the question. Neither of them contains a div.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I found out that my first fiddle is wrong. I found another example that does work and shows how the stopPropagation() work:

```
var divs = document.getElementsByTagName('div');

for(var i=0; i<divs.length; i++) {
  divs[i].onclick = function( e ) {
    e = e || window.event;
    var target = e.target || e.srcElement;

    //e.stopPropagation ? e.stopPropagation() : ( e.cancelBubble = true );
    if ('bubbles' in e) { // all browsers except IE before version 9
        if (e.bubbles) {
            e.stopPropagation();
            alert("The propagation of the event is stopped.");
        } else {
            alert("The event cannot propagate up the DOM hierarchy.");
        }
    } else { // Internet Explorer before version 9
        // always cancel bubbling
        e.cancelBubble = true;
        alert("The propagation of the event is stopped.");
    }

    this.style.backgroundColor = 'yellow';

    alert("target = " + target.className + ", this=" + this.className );

    this.style.backgroundColor = '';
  }
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/MekZii/wNGSx/2/

The example is found at the following link with some reading material:
http://javascript.info/tutorial/bubbling-and-capturing

Answer (score 10):

Events bubble from the element clicked on up to the document object.

Any event handler on a div is going to fire before an event handler on the body (since the body is an ancestor of it in the DOM).

By the time the event reaches the body, it is too late to prevent it from acting on a div.

Comment: So does that mean there is no way of clicking the link without firing the div's onclick? If thats true then I dont see why and when the stopPropagation() function is used.

Comment: With an event handler attached to the link - sure. You have an event handler attached to the body though.

Answer (score -2):

Use below code wherever you want to cancel the event bubbling from child to parent in HTML

```
event.cancelBubble = true;
```

By using this way you stop the bubbling of event further upward from child to parent elements.